# ASP.NET 4 RouteDictionary does not take the default values

Tags: c#, asp.net, routes

I have this route in ASP.NET 4

```
routes.MapPageRoute("Professions",     // Route Name  
 "authors/profession/{Profession}/{letter}/page{pager}",  // Url and Parameters  
  "~/Authors/Profession/Default.aspx", true, 
new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary { { "letter", "a" }, { "pager", "1" } }); //
```

It works if I access the page like this 
http://www.mysite.com/authors/profession/actor/a/page1

but this does not work http://www.mysite.com/authors/profession/actor  (it should add automatically the letter 'a' and page 1, what I am doing wrong?

Comment: It wouldn't 'add' it to the url and the url you describe wouldn't match that route because it doesn't follow the correct format (ie 'page' is not present).

Comment: and how can I make it work with and without the /page in url ? and get the default values?

Comment: Have provided an answer below - hope it helps / works. Rob

Answer (score 0):

The problem you got here is the text "page" in the route which as **after** your `{letter}` token (which you are not providing in the example url).

For the routing engine to match that route, you would need both a "letter" and the **text** 'page' somewhere in the url. So your example `/authors/profession/actor` would **not** match whereas `/authors/profession/actor/a/page` **would** match and use the default value of 1 for the `{pager}` token.

I think the best way to approach this would be the following route setting:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("Professions",     // Route Name  
 "authors/profession/{profession}/{letter}/{pager}",  // Url and Parameters  
  "~/Authors/Profession/Default.aspx", true, 
new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary { { "letter", "a" }, { "pager", "1" } });
```

Essentially, just take 'page' text out of the route so that when you have `/authors/profession/actor` it would go straight to the letter "a" and page "1". And a full url would be something like `/authors/profession/actor/d/34`.

Does that make sense? Your routing is perfectly valid, but you would **always** have to provide something for the `{letter}` token and have the text 'page' in there too.